# Why Django cannot extends my form.html contact page and returns a TemplateSyntaxError or an Exception Thrown?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a contact page ("/contact-us/") as a modular app instead of the similar already working contact page ("/contact/") located in the "/app/" directory. The former is failing, returning either Exception Thrown or TemplateSyntaxError while trying to {% extends %} the form.html with its base.html.

My file structure:

```
BlogDjango
|-BlogDjango
| | settings.py
| | urls.py
|-app
| |-Templates
| | | base.html
| | | form.html
|-blogpost
|-contactform
| |-Templates
| | | base.html
| | | form.html
| | forms.py
| | views.py
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'app','templates'),os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'contactform','templates')],...
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body></html>
```

form.html

```
{% extends base.html %}

{% block content %}
{% if title %}
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endif %}

<form method='POST' action='.'> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type='submit'>Send</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

It seems that Django doesn't recognise that the base.html is located in the same directory than the form.html and therefor cannot extend it.
So I get those two errors thrown at me:

```
Exception Thrown:
    Failed lookup for key [base] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: <function csrf.<locals>._get_val at 0x000001D62DDBBAF0>>, 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/contact-us/'>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <function AuthenticationMiddleware.process_request.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001D62DCDDAF0>>, 'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x000001D62DC88100>, 'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x000001D62DC82670>, 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'INFO': 20, 'SUCCESS': 25, 'WARNING': 30, 'ERROR': 40}}, {}, {'form': <ContactForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(full_name;email;content)>}]
```

Or:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /contact-us/
Could not parse the remainder: '/templates/base.html' from '/templates/base.html'
```

So my question is:

Why does Django fail at extending form.html with base.html when it works in another directory?

Comment: Quote the template name, so: `{% extends "base.html" %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to write the `extends` template tag as:

```
{% extends base.html %}
```

Here you haven't quoted `base.html` which means it is a *variable* lookup, hence Django tries to find `base` in the context and since there is no such variable it fails. It then gives you an error because it needs this variable to extend the correct template. You need to quote the template name so that it is considered a *string*:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now!
I've tried so many things that I forgot to check the most basic one...